# Verify Configuration of multiple OpenAM and OpenDJ

Tags: openam, opendj

I have a solution that uses 2 OpenAMs (v12.0.0) and 2 OpenDJs (v2.6.0). The OpenAMs are behind a load balancer and the OpenDJs are configured so 1 openAM will prefer 1 openDJ and the other OpenAM will prefer the other OpenDJ. Each OpenAM machine has the OpenDJ it prefers hosted on it. I followed this post to configure the OpenDJ instances in OpenAM

[Original Blog post](http://azlabs.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/openam-data-store-high-availability-and.html)

So once I got my OpenAM configured with two servers in the site I then looked at the value of com.iplanet.am.lbcookie.value in the site config which reportedly should give me the serverId and then calculated the siteId to be 1 more than the highest serverId. I got 01 for the serverid of my first instance and 03 for my second. So in my LDAP server values I have the following

opendj1:1389|01|04

opendj2:1389|03|04

From my reading this should mean openDJ1 will be used by openam1 (server id 01) and openDJ2 will be used by openam2 (server id 03). If OpenAM 1 can't access OpenDJ1 it will failover to OpenDJ2. Is this correct?

The reason I ask is that if I look at the OpenAM access logs I see almost a 50 - 50 split in the number of requests that each instance is handling. Though if I look in the OpenDJ access logs the requests seem to be favouring OpenDJ1 ie 75 - 25 split between OpenDJ1 and OpenDJ2.

Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the access logs of both DJ servers and identify which AM server is responsible for what proportion of traffic. Once you see the culprit, you should make sure that the OpenAM server in question doesn't have any connection issues mentioned in its debug logs.

There is a good chance that one of the AM servers had to failover to the other DJ instance. Please keep in mind, that after a failover and recovery, OpenAM retains the connections made during the failover and will keep on sending heartbeat requests to that DJ node.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So if an OpenAM did failover the connections will stay with the failed over OpenDJ until the connections get refreshed and then the new connections will open with the normal OpenDJ?

Comment: When the failed server recovers, OpenAM will detect its reappearance and will use that server from then on (There was a fairly recent bug around CTS connections sticking to the second server though).